# list of untagges ec2 instances in aws account using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

The code below is giving me the result for one specified region, can anyone help me how to get all untagged ec2 instances information across all regions in one aws account?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
import json, ast

instances = [i for i in boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2').instances.all()]

for i in instances:
    d = (i.tags[0])
    d2 = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(d))
    if ( d2['Value'] == "" ):
            print i.instance_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get list of all regions. Loop through each region and execute your code. Something like this:

```
def do_tags(region):
  instances = [i for i in boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region).instances.all()]

  for i in instances:
      d = (i.tags[0])
      d2 = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(d))
      if ( d2['Value'] == "" ):
              print i.instance_id

regions = boto3.session.Session().get_available_regions('ec2')
for region in regions:
  print 'Checking region:', region
  do_tags(region)
```

Comment: Hai, With this script, I am able to get the information from my default user account.How to get untagged information from all of my user accounts??